# "Kernel not found" error in Jupyter notebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, kernel

Trying to open a .ipynb file in Jupyter notebook but getting the following error message: "Kernel not found. Could not find a kernel matching conda_mxnet_p36. Please select a kernel." How do I try and fix the issue? Currently following a tutorial for Amazon Web Services.

Tried choosing "conda_mxnet_p36" but halfway through running the code ran into an error.